# Final Pay ף ??? - Exists or Not?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading

Just confirming that there doesn't exist anywhere in Tanach a final Pay (not Fay but rather a ף with a Dagesh). If so, it is a fascinating that it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

It does exist and appears precisely once in Tanach, in [Mishlei 30:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c2830.htm#6):

> אַל־**תּ֥וֹסְףְּ** עַל־דְּבָרָ֑יו פֶּן־יוֹכִ֖יחַ בְּךָ֣ וְנִכְזָֽבְתָּ׃

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! (sorry for the late response)